# How to Send Emai SMTP with template in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, email, html

I follow this [respitory](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-custom-smtp/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Test/Index.php) to send SMTP email and it successfully done, but right now if i want to set the template for email i have to use setBodyHtml() like this:

```
$body = '<html><head> </head> <body> <p> test </p> </body> </html>';
$this->_message->setBodyHtml($body);
```

the above code can generate html code for email in magento 2, but i think this is not the right way for using email template in magento 2, what i want is using template like magento documentation in [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this link](http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/)  to send email with template in your magento 2.

**FOR SMTP:**  [send html using SMTP](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html-mails.html)

**UPDATE:**

```
 $emailTemplateVariables = array();
 $emailTempVariables['myvar'] = $myvar;

 $senderName = 'test';

 $senderEmail = 'sender@test.com';

 $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
 $postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);

 $sender = [
     'name' => $senderName,
     'email' => $senderEmail,
 ];

 $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($email)
                ->setReplyTo($senderEmail)            
                ->getTransport();               
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: and how to use it with smtp config ?

Comment: smtp config means do u have any extension or what ?

Comment: i follow this [respitory](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-custom-smtp/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Test/Index.php) to set smtp for set the message and send the email

Comment: @simpleguy: magento have their own function to send mail, Is there any special requirement? I updated my answer , please check if this helps you

Comment: Check this i hope you are looking for this https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html-mails.html